# Python: To export the scene in VPython as common 3D vector file

Tags: python, export, cad, 3ds, vpython

Is there any way to export the scene drawn by `VPython` as `DXF`/`DWG`/`3DS` or any other common 3D vector formats?

Answer (score 2):

There is a User-Contributed Programs povexport that can export a VPython scene to POV-Ray.

http://vpython.org/contents/contributed.html

Comment: As far as I know it just exports to `POV` format. In addition it does not support `convex` for export. Anyway, is there any `POV` to `DXF` converter?